Galaxy S9 ultra can’t read from exFAT SSD?
I’m new to Android tablets having previously used Apple exclusively, and I could use some advice getting an external WD 2tb SSD to work.
My SSD was formatted as exFAT on a Windows device and filled with various MKV files of 10gb or higher. The drive is recognised perfectly fine by my iPad, but doesn’t show up at all on my S9.
I tried reformatting the SSD, and the empty drive now shows on the S9. However, as soon as I start putting MKV files on the drive again, it no longer shows up.
Can anyone advise what might be causing this?

Seems similar issue: Exfat misbehaviour on SD card

Official ExFAT support was introduced to Android pretty late, therefore a lot of manufacturer modified Android and added support for it. Unfortunately these modifications often had bugs so not everything may work. Another potential problem could be power supply. An SSD requires a bit more power than an USB Stick and your S9 and it's battery are a bit aged and may not be able to provide the required power. I would try to use a self-powered USB hub in between SSD and phone.
